# how to reflect download progress onto QtableView or QtableWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want to make a download tool.

I use the following [code](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27934/) for downloading.

I am facing a problem:

I don’t know how to reflect download progress onto QTableView or QTableWidget?
Especially, downloading 2 or more files at the same time.
For instance, how to reflect download progress onto this QTableView?

[image]

Can anyone give a little sample? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you have a look this question ,it is more clear http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27934/

Answer (score 3):

You can use QTableView and an item delegate.

There is an example of a delegate that draws a progress bar in the official doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html

Answer (score 2):

in the `QTableWidget` you could use the `set cellWidget(QWidget*)` to insert a `QProgressBar` and implement the logic to set its value ...